# How to SELECT an articles and its comments from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I read an article and its comments from mysql database with two separate queries as

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id='$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$title=$row['title'];
........
```

AND

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id='$id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$comment_title=$row['title'];
.........
}
```

Is the best way to read this set of data from database? OR
Is it possible to catch the data through one query or one transaction?

**NOTE:** My issue is that first query for article is only for one row; but the second one needs a loop to process (and display in html) several comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT articles.title as article_title, comments.title as comment_title FROM articles LEFT JOIN comments ON articles.article_id = comments.article_id WHERE articles.article_id = '$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$article_title=$row['article_title'];
$comment_title=$row['comment_title '];
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way -

```
SELECT a.*, c.* FROM articles a
  LEFT JOIN comments c
    ON a.article_id = c.article_id
WHERE a.article_id='$id';
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is the best way to read this set of data from database?

Sure, it is.

> Is it possible to catch the data through one query

Yes, it's possible but there is no point in doing that.

Why do you ask?

Comment: Why do you ask? To make me sure :)